# Create "difference raster" in PostGIS / GeoServer / OpenLayers stack

Tags: javascript, openlayers, postgis, geoserver

I've inherited a project with a geodata stack comprising

- a PostGIS DB (so far unrelated to this),
- a time-enabled GeoServer ImageMosaic of a raster time series (Source is GeoTIFFs on the filesystem, not DB)
- an OpenLayers (still v5.3.0) front end to visualize and query the data.

I need to add a functionality that creates a "difference raster" (i.e. Difference Raster = Raster 2 vals - Raster 1 vals) from two arbitrary rasters of the time series. This could also be done just visually, via "blending" of sorts etc., as the actual data query is performed on the actual raster data via GetFeatureInfo, etc.

I know that Leaflet is capable of such things directly, but I haven't seen a pendant in OpenLayers to create such a "difference raster" either mathematically or just by visual trickery so far.

As far as I can make out, my options are:

- Migrate the entire front end to Leaflet.

  - The front end does a lot of fancy stuff, much of which is OpenLayers-specific, and this option seems very time-expensive.
- Make use of GeoServer's WebProcessingService plugin

  - GeoServer's WCS only implemented addition and multiplication from GeoTools so far, and my Java skills will most likely not suffice to implement this.
- Make use of PostGIS's raster extension

  - This can easily be done via PostGIS' ST_MapAlgebra, however this would require some probably very hacky OL - DB interface that screams security issues.
- Use third-pary JS libraries

  - Where I'm still searching for libraries that can actually perform map algebra across two rasters, not just on one raster itself such as OpenLayer's [raster source example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/raster.html).

Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

In terms of third-party libraries it is worth mentioning that the source GTIFFs are high-res drone images (~ 9000x9000 pixels each), so loading the entire two source TIFFs to perform map algebra is likely a performance issue.

Comment: The OpenLayers raster source can have multiple sources so you can perform difference or other comparisons https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-compare-m20mw

Comment: How about multiplying one by `-1` and then adding them using the existing functionality

Comment: If both images are rendered to the same canvas you might be able to get a result by using globalCompositeOperation https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-compare-forked-65pt1